# "This URL contains an invalid domain"-error when registering meteor app with facebook app

Tags: meteor, facebook-login

I am creating a Meteor app with Facebook login. It works fine on localhost, but when I deploy it to meteor.com, it doesn't work. Facebook does not even let me register the app. When I enter the Site URL, I get the error message:
"This URL contains an invalid domain", though the domain,

```
   http://nr_siteaces.meteor.com
```

is a perfectly valid URL. I have tried adding meteor.com as app domain, but that does not improve things. I have also read the following articles, but they do not adress the issue:

[Meteor login with facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926521/meteor-login-with-facebook)

[Meteor app - facebook login - popup doesn't close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896610/meteor-app-facebook-login-popup-doesnt-close)

[Facebook Authentication with Facebook app error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107882/facebook-authentication-with-facebook-app-error)

[Facebook App: localhost no longer works as app domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295872/facebook-app-localhost-no-longer-works-as-app-domain)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the only solution for me was to remove the underscore (_) from the URL. I couldn't find any documentation which explains why the underscore invalidates the URL but it seems to do so in Facebook's view.

Edit: This answer seems to shed some light on the "underscore in a URL" issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183140/2088912 so I guess Facebook is just following the rules.